# Which character set and font (combination) is used for Japanese characters on Macintosh to create a pdf file?

Tags: fonts, character

What could be the best combination of "character set" and "font" for japanese language to create a pdf file using java, on macintosh (OS Sierra)?

Any help will be gratefully appreciated.
Thank you.
Code snippet is given here:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
import com.lowagie.text.FontFactory;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class PdfCharacterSet {
/*
     * This will create a pdf file with the name of hello.pdf in the directory where this java file is executed. 
     */
public static final String DEST = "..\\hello.pdf";
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new PdfCharacterSet().createPdf(DEST);
    }

public void createPdf(String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        document.open();

        // text is "日本列島における人類の歴史は";
        String text = "\u65E5\u672C\u5217\u5CF6\u306B\u304A\u3051\u308B\u4EBA\u985E\u306E\u6B74\u53F2\u306F";

        Font baseFont = FontFactory.getFont("arial unicode ms", "Shift_JIS");
        document.add(new Paragraph(text, baseFont));
        document.close();
    }
}
```